# ElasticSearch Curator delete unless last entry

Tags: elasticsearch-curator

Is there a way to stop curator deleting the last index when deleting by time?

```
actions:
1:
  action: delete_indices
  description: Delete kube- indices older than 14 days. Ignore the error if there are none and exit cleanly.
  options:
    disable_action: False
    ignore_empty_list: True      
  filters:
  - filtertype: pattern
    kind: prefix
    value: kube-
  - filtertype: age
    source: name
    direction: older
    timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
    unit: days
    unit_count: 14
```

I have this which works great to keep a currently running K8s cluster logs in check. However when we move AWS region the log name changes e.g. from `kube-eu-west-1-<date>` to `kube-eu-west-2-<date>`.

Curator diligently cleans up all the data after 14 days. What I'd like is to prevent it from removing the last entry for a particular index, so there is always a record of what happened the last time the cluster was in that region.

*(It would also "fix" some less well written pieces of code that throw errors when the data they expect to be there has legitimately gone away).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`count` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.7/filtertype_count.html):

```
filters:
  # your existing filters go BEFORE the count filter...
  - filtertype: count
    count: 1
```

This example should exclude (in spite of the `exclude: false`) the most recent index from the list of actionable indices, preserving it. If this is not the index you want to exclude, explore using `exclude: true/false` (default is `true`), and/or `reverse: true/false` (default is `true`) until it excludes the index you want.

**NOTE:** Always use the `--dry-run` flag to test your filters before deploying them on actual data. Iterate until it looks right. Use of `loglevel: DEBUG` in your client settings will show how filters make their decisions, if that helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, my google-fu was failing me!